# How to add multiple data in $_REQUEST in php

Tags: php, request

i would like to know how can i add multiple data in $_REQUEST in php. This is what i currently have:

```
<?php
//1
if(isset($_REQUEST['content'])){
//2
$size          = $_REQUEST['size'];
$content       = $_REQUEST['content'];
$correction    = strtoupper($_REQUEST['correction']);
$encoding      = $_REQUEST['encoding'];

//3
$rootUrl = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=$size&chl=$content&choe=$encoding&chld=$correction";

//4
echo '<img src="'.$rootUrl.'">';
}
?>
```

At the $content reqest, i would like to be able to put something like this in the
  $content = $_REQUEST :

**(fixed test that will always display, no matter of content)+'content'+(another fixed text).**

The problem is, i dont know how to combine these in a single Request. I also get an error, if i try to add ":" in the text that will always show.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to catch data from a HTML Form?

Comment: Yes, from a HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are posting a HTML form use $_POST or $_GET depending on the HTML form methode tag.

Its a much better practice. Because you know the form type.

I guess you form looks something like this:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="content" value="Mickey">
    <input type="text" name="contentTwo" value="Mouse">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To get the form inputs:

```
<?php

$content = $_POST["content"];
$contentTwo = $_POST["contentTwo"];
```

Just use the name of the input to get the value out of the post variable.
Its that easy. You can use as much inputs as you like.

Notice I use POST in the html Action attribute and in PHP.